# Why the explained variance is a "ratio of sums" and not a "sums of ratio"?

Tags: variance

Let $\pmb{y} = [y_1, y_2, ..., y_i, ..., y_N]$ some data and $\pmb{\hat{y}} = [\hat{y}_1, \hat{y}_2, ..., \hat{y}_i, ..., \hat{y}_N]$ their estimates. Let also be $\bar{y} = \frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N y_i$.

To my understanding, the explained variance for estimates $\pmb{\hat{y}}$ is:
$$
\sum_i (\hat{y_i} - \bar{y})^2
\over
\sum_i (y_i - \bar{y})^2
$$

I'm just wondering why we do not compute it like so:
$$
\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N {
F(\hat{y_i} - \bar{y})
\over
F(y_i - \bar{y})
}
$$

where $F(x)$ can be a monotone function which prevents the denominator to be zero, e.g. $F(x) = e^{(x^2)}$ of $F(x) = log(1 + x^2)$.

To me, it looks much easier to understand the second formulation, which compares index by index and then averages everything.

---

Edit: in the original formulation, I did not use $F$.

Comment: Contemplate what happens when any of the responses $y_i$ is extremely close to the mean response $\bar y.$

Comment: Even worse, what if you have some $y_i = \bar{y}?$

Comment: Ok, but we could use some monotone function, e.g. e^x or log(1 + x)

Comment: But what relationship does that $F$ have to the regression equation? // What is your interpretation of your equation. Say you get $0.73$. What does that mean?

Comment: It's not important the meaning of 0.73 by itself. Even in the traditional formulation, 0.73 has no real meaning because there's the square funciton. What matters is the fact that 0.73 is larger then, say, 0.67 and smaller than 0.97 and that the measure is linear in the ratio (i.e. 0.3 and 0.5 have the same "distance" of 0.6 and 0.8).

Comment: Variance is not measured by single samples, that's why it's not defined on a per-sample basis

Answer (score 0):

#### Some geometric intuition why we use ratio of the sum and not sum of the ratio

You could consider the observations $y_1, y_2, \dots y_n$ as being spread in an n-dimensional space. If the errors of the observations $y_1, y_2, \dots y_n$ are independent and normally distributed then the observations will be spread like a spherically symmetric cloud.

For a linear model the fitted solution $\hat y_1,\hat y_2, \dots \hat y_n$ is a point in a plane spanned by the vectors $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ that create the equation

$$\hat y = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \dots + \beta_n x_n$$

[image: geometric view]

In this viewpoint - where the residuals are spherically symmetric distributed and the solution of the regression is a projection onto some plane - the direction of the residual vector is not so much important and it is all about the *length* of the residual vector.

Comment: Very nice explanation, thanks a lot! However, in a real-world scenario, it is hard to assume that errors are i.i.d.

Comment: @fortea in a real-world situation the errors are actually quite often independent. And otherwise, you just mostly get variations of the simplified case in this answer (e.g. mixed-effects models or generalized least squares). I had not yet finished my explanation (I still wanted to plot a rotated version of this plane spanned y the vectors $X_1$ and $X_2$), and maybe I will add one of these variants to the explanation.